# Error accessing field (using Hibernate/JPA)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, orm

I'm having this error

> Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer
>   fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.entity.LoginEntity.id] by reflection
>   for persistent property
>   [fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.entity.LoginEntity#id] : 2; nested
>   exception is
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [private java.lang.Integer
>   fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.entity.LoginEntity.id] by reflection
>   for persistent property
>   [fearx.projects.animal.finder.api.entity.LoginEntity#id] : 2

While I try to do this:

```
public void registerUser(OwnerEntity body) {
    ownerRepository.save(body);
    loginRepository.save(new LoginEntity(body.getEmail(), body.getPassword()));
    LoginEntity loginEntity = loginRepository.findByEmail(body.getEmail());
    OwnerEntity ownerEntity = ownerRepository.findByEmail(body.getEmail());
    ownerLoginRepository.save(new OwnerLoginEntity(loginEntity.getId(),ownerEntity.getId()));
}
```

My entitys:

```
@Entity(name = "owner_login")
@Data
public class OwnerLoginEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = LoginEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_login", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Integer login;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = OwnerEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_owner", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Integer owner;

    public OwnerLoginEntity(Integer login, Integer owner) {
        this.login = login;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class OwnerEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String phone;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = LostPetEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_pet", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Integer id_pet;
}
```

---

```
 @Entity(name = "login")
    @Data
    public class LoginEntity {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;
        @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String email;
        @Column
        private String password;

        public LoginEntity(String email, String password) {
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public LoginEntity() {
        }

}
```

Comment: Post your repositories classes, hibernate and lombok version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O don't know what database you have, but try to change the approach of GeneratedValue like this:

```java
@Entity(name = "owner_login")
@Data
public class OwnerLoginEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private LoginEntity login;

    @ManyToOne
    private OwnerEntity owner;

    public OwnerLoginEntity(LoginEntity login, OwnerEntity owner) {
        this.login = login;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Then you can call `ownerLoginRepository.save(new OwnerLoginEntity(loginEntity, ownerEntity));`

Comment: I should do this to all @GeneratedValue in my project?

Comment: I have MySQL btw!

Comment: actually, only the `@GeneratedValue` should work with MySQL... 
but if you try change the use of `@ManyToOne` annotation, works?!